# JsonCpp to parse from url

Tags: c++, json, api

curl_jsoncpp_example.cpp : https://gist.github.com/connormanning/41efa6075515019e499c

```
#include <json/json.h>
```

> g++ main.cpp -ljsoncpp -lcurl -o example.out
>
> > so error :
> >     main.cpp:8:23: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory

server did not support this, so i edited this section

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
```

And now I'm faced with this error :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cstdint:35:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:44:5: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
     std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());
     ^
main.cpp:44:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());
                                ^
main.cpp:44:60: error: ‘httpData’ was not declared in this scope
     std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());
```

I wanted to use this https://linux.tips/programming/how-to-install-and-use-json-cpp-library-on-ubuntu-linux-os
But this is only for files inside the server

I want to get the information from a link json that is and print

exampel json link : http://date.jsontest.com

ptint json data ["time"]  C++ or C ?

If you are familiar with PHP, this code is simply written :

```
<?php
$time = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://date.jsontest.com'),true);
echo $time['time']; 
?>
```

**But how to write in C++ or C ?**

Please help me

Comment: Did you try to read the error message?

Comment: Yes . I've written errors on the top question - You have a good source to get information from a link json api ?

Comment: The answer is in the error message. Look at this carefully.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/115510/    :                            
                        But not solved error

Comment: 1. Learn how to read compiler errors 2. Learn how to use `jsoncpp` alone 3. Learn how to use `libcurl` alone 4. Combine 1+2+3 4. PROFIT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***example.cpp :***

```
// telegram : @ELsAnEHSAN - c++ 
// g++ example.cpp -o example -lcurl -ljsoncpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://date.jsontest.com/");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value obj;
    reader.parse(readBuffer, obj); 
    std::cout << obj["time"].asString() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If needed :

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl-dev
:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
:~$ sudo apt-get install libjson-c-dev
:~$ sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev
```

> compiling :   **g++ example.cpp -o example -lcurl -ljsoncpp**
>
> run : **./example**

Answer (score 0):

As S.M mentioned,the error message gives the solution.

Try compiling your program with the:
`-std=c++11` flag and see if it works.

If it doesn't, please post more code and all the error/warnings you get